# can't update in terminal or software update

Tags: ppa, gwibber

I keep getting

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/gwibber-daily/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
```

when I do a `apt-get update`, also get failed to download repository information when i try software update.

How do i fix these?

Comment: Hopefully you have an active internet connection and that your connection isn't restricted and that

Comment: There are no installation candidates for Trusty for this PPA.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are using a non valid ppa

### 1. Disable the PPA

Please disable (by unchecking or removing) the gwibber ppa via **Software & Updates** (from Terminal: `software-properties-gtk`) in the **Other Software** tab

[image]

[This AskUbuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed) explains removing PPA's as well.

### 2. Update package informations

Now open a Terminal and re-run

```
sudo apt update
```

or

```
sudo apt-get update
```

to update your package informations.

### 3. Install updates (optional)

You should then be able to run

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

or

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

to upgrade your packages as well.

### Regarding the gwibber daily ppa

If you try to open up the [ppa url](http://ppa.launchpad.net/gwibber-daily/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages) in your browser you'll see as well that the entire url seems non existent.

I've checked the [project url](https://launchpad.net/~gwibber-daily/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) and it seems like precise is the last supported Ubuntu release for this ppa. I can only guess what you are using (trusty) as you haven't mentioned it in your post.

Answer (score 0):

From a terminal use `--remove` flag to remove the PPA:-Similar to how the PPA was added
`sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:whatever/ppa`
FAs a safer alternative, you can install `ppa-purge` 
`sudo ppa-purge ppa:whatever/ppa`
Alternatively hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and run `software-properties-gtk` [image: Software Sources]

Click on `Other Software` tab, you'll see that each PPA have two lines here, one for the compiled packages and one for the source, `Uncheck` both lines to disable a PPA.Then update your sources list
`sudo apt-get update`
and try to upgrade again
`sudo apt-get upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem aswell, I solved it by running  "software-properties-gtk", then go to "ubuntu software" tab and select another server from " download from" drop-down menu. In my case I chose Duke server in the US.